# multiplying polynomials from linked lists in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

The problem is my program crashes and i don't know why.I need to implement a function that multiplies two polynomials. The coefficients of those polynomials are stored in linked lists. the most significant coefficient is in head of list so that according to coefficient place in the list, the power of x differs.  here's the polynomial class

```
    class polynomial
{
public: 
int* multiply_poly(list A, list B, int m, int n);
};
```

the function:

```
    int* polynomial::multiply_poly(list A, list B, int m, int n)
    {  node* a = new node();
        node* b = new node();
        a=A.chain;
        b=B.chain;
 // Initialize the porduct polynomial
    int *prod = new int[m+n-1];
    for (int i = 0; i<m+n-1; i++)
         prod[i] = 0;
// Multiply two polynomials term by term

   // Take ever term of first polynomial
for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
       {  

/ Multiply the current term of first polynomial
     // with every term of second polynomial.
for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
             prod[i+j] += (a->data)*(b->data);
             b=b->next;
            cout<<prod[i+j] }
         a=a->next;
       } return prod;}
```

print polynomial function:

```
void printPoly(int poly[], int n)
    {
        for (int i=n; i>0; i--)
        {cout << poly[i];
           if (i != 0) cout << "x^" << i ;
           if (i != n-1)
           cout << " + ";  }}
```

main functin:

```
int main(){
    list L_1; list L_2;

    L_1.add(6);
    L_1.add (10);
    L_1.add(0); //filling list
    L_1.add(5);


    L_2.add(4);
    L_2.add(2);
    L_2.add(1);

int m=L_1.size();
int n=L_2.size();

  polynomial p; int *re ;
  re=p.multiply_poly(L_1,L_2,m,n);
  cout << "\nProduct polynomial is \n";
    printPoly(re, m+n-1);
return 0;}
```

the node class:

```
class node
{double data; node * next;
public:
node() {data=0; next=NULL;}
node(int d) :data(d), next(NULL ) {}
double getData() {return data;}
void setData(doube d) {data=d;}
node * getNext() {return next;}
void setNext( node * n) {next =n;}
friend class list;
friend class polynomial; };
```

the list class:

```
class list
class list{
node *chain;
public: list() { chain= nullptr; }
void add(int item);  //at start of list

int size();
friend class polynomial;};
```

add function:

```
void list::add( int item) // add at front
{
node *temp= new node(item);
temp->setNext(chain);
chain =temp;
}
```

size function:

```
int list::size() {
if(chain==nullptr){ return 0;}
else {
node *p = chain;
int count=0;
while (p!=nullptr) {count++; p=p->next;}
return count;
}};
```

Comment: Fairly certain that in `void printPoly(int poly[], int n)` the loop `for (int i=n; i>0; i--)` should be `for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)` since array indexing is zero based. Within that loop is a big clue: `if (i != 0)` and as written `i` will never be `0`.

Comment: Can you give more information about the crash? Where in your code does it occur? Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger attached? In a case like this the debugger should help you find the problem quite fast